# Stick header recyclerView cabeçalho fixo

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou implementando o efeito de `stick header` em uma `recyclerView` no meu aplicativo. Criei um subclasse de `RecyclerView.ItemDecorator` e fiz minha implementação, o efeito foi aplicado na `Recycler`, porém os `headers` estão sumindo da tela antes do próximo header chegar no topo, pesquisei sobre como posso fazer isso e fiz algumas mudanças no código, mas ainda continua com o mesmo problema. Podem me dar uma dica de como posso fazer com que um header da minha `RecyclerView` só saia do topo da tela quando o próximo header chegar no topo?

Comment: Poderia postar o código que você tem no momento?